# How to check for current route url with a dynamic parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, navigation

I want to hide footer on my `course-report` component. If I use this below code for other Components like `/login` this works, but when I use this code with id route this does not work. How can I solve this problem?

```
router.events.forEach((event) = > {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
        if (event['url'] == 'coursereport/:id') {
            this.showFoot = false;
        } else {
            // console.log("NU")
            this.showFoot = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should probably check if string contains a value rather than equating it, and omit the `:id`:

```
router.events.forEach((event) => {
          if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            if (event['url'].includes('coursereport/') {
              ...
            } else {
              ...
            }
          }
        });
```